# codeigniter child function after submit parent function

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller

In my project I have a controller call load and  it has a fuction call search() that has a form, i want to submit this form in a child function of search() like this,,

```
localhost/ci/index.php/load/search
```

to

```
localhost/ci/index.php/load/search/something/
```

how can i do this after submission a form?

this is my contoller like

```
class Load extends CI_Controller {
    function search() {
        $this->load->view('search');
    }
    function something() {
        $this->load->view('something');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not child function `something()`

You can define routes as per your requirements.

After search function call , you can use `redirect()` method, that will redirect to your `route` like 'base_url/controller/search/searchresult/'.

Routes.php

```
$route['Load/search/searchresult'] = 'Load/something';
```

Load Controller code :

```
class Load extends CI_Controller {
   function search() {
       $this->load->view('search');

       // after form submission
       redirect('Load/search/searchresult');
   }
   function something() {
      $this->load->view('something');
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a child function of search function so you can call it like
`localhost/ci/index.php/load/something`/
Add this url to your form action and your form will be submitted to `something()` function

Comment: i wanted to implement a child function like  "localhost/ci/index.php/load/search/something/" this. how can i do this?

Comment: Its not a child function in ur case something will be an argument of search function

Comment: can u provide some resource link?

Comment: Can you please tell me what u want to do ?

Comment: Yes,  i want to load result of search function, but dont want change the search, thus i need something that, load the search under search function i i could achive result like "base_url/controller/search/searchresult/", thats it

Comment: Cant understand :( i think u need www.tutorialspoint.com to understand basic flow of codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

For clarity: `localhost/ci/index.php/load/search/something/` does this...

Enters `search()` method of `Load` and provides `something` as a parameter e.g. `search($param = 'something')` (this is not correct syntax but just for show).

```
function search($term = null) {

    if (is_null($term)) {
        // user hasn't searched
    } else {
        // user searched for $term e.g. something   
    }

}
```

The only way you can achieve what you want is to either use the above somehow to your advantage knowing that `/something` will have to be the search parameter. Or you can use routing as another answerer suggested.